# Boolean result of the nested boolean values

Tags: php, arrays, nested, boolean

I'm modelling an access function that should return boolean value based on next structure on nested array, which contains only boolean values:

1. based on dimension, comparison of the should be made either OR or AND type
2. first level is OR, next level is AND, next level is OR and so on
3. final result should return TRUE or FALSE

For example I have these arrays with expected results:

```
array(TRUE) -> TRUE
array(FALSE) -> FALSE
```

evidently...

```
array(TRUE, FALSE) -> TRUE
```

because of TRUE | FALSE

```
array(TRUE, array(FALSE)) -> TRUE
```

because of TRUE | (FALSE)

```
array(FALSE, array(FALSE, TRUE)) -> FALSE
```

because of FALSE | (FALSE && TRUE)

```
array(FALSE, array(TRUE, array(FALSE, TRUE))) -> TRUE
```

because of FALSE | (TRUE && (FALSE | TRUE))

What I'm doing here is just changing comparison method on every other level of the nested array.

PHP language example would be nice, but any prototype that I can transfer to PHP is accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of mutual-recursion, using the [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function

- `do_or` applies the `OR` operator on the entire array
- `do_and` applies the `AND` operator on the entire array
- if an element of the array is an array itself, the functions apply each other

The Code:

```
function do_or($x,$y)
{
  if (is_array($y))
  {
    if (empty($y))
      {$y=FALSE;}
    else
      {$y=array_reduce($y,"do_and",TRUE);}
  }
  return $x||$y;
}

function do_and($x,$y)
{
  if (is_array($y))
  {
    if (empty($y))
      {$y=TRUE;}
    else
      {$y=array_reduce($y,"do_or",FALSE);}
  }
  return $x && $y;
}

$answer=array_reduce($arr,"do_or",FALSE);
```

This code could be optimized, but I guess it illustrates the idea

Comment: Technically better to use `return $x||$y;
` rather than `return $x|$y;`.... `|` is a bitwise operator rather than a boolean operator; but kudos for use or array_reduce()

Comment: How do you test these functions with the last example: array(FALSE, array(TRUE, array(FALSE, TRUE))) ?

Comment: @PHPGAE run the code with `$arr=array(FALSE, array(TRUE, array(FALSE, TRUE)));`